# How To Give Shape to LinearLayout's Background image?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, shapes

i want to give *shape* to`LinearLayout's` `backgroundimage`. i am using following xml.
but it is not displaying image while displaying only curve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp"/>
    <item>
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/locationlable" />
    </item>
</shape>
```

Comment: are you trying to round the corners of a bitmap?

Comment: but i set the image in linear layout background so how  can i give shape for linearlayout background image

Comment: the easiest way is to edit the bitmap to give it rounded corners.  If that is not an option, check out Romain Guy's article on rounding the corners of images: http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

In your layout

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#FFF">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@xml/shape_round_rect"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</FrameLayout>
```

& in your xml for shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="15dip" />

    <stroke
        android:width="5dip"
        android:color="#FFF" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a [layer-list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) :

like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource"
        android:id="@[+][package:]id/resource_name"
        android:top="dimension"
        android:right="dimension"
        android:bottom="dimension"
        android:left="dimension" />
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to draw circular then you would use a different shape:

```
android:shape="ring"
```

and if you want to draw a rectangle, then use below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#000000" />


 </shape>
```

for more info visit this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: but i have a background image in linearlayout so how can i use shape with image